# variable based on other variables in R

Tags: r

I have a df like this

```
my_df <- data.frame(
    b1 = c(2, 6, 3, 6, 4, 2, 1, 9, NA), 
    b2 = c(100, 4, 106, 102, 6, 6, 1, 1, 7), 
    b3 = c(75, 79, 8, 0, 2, 3, 9, 5, 80), 
    b4 = c(NA, 6, NA, 10, 12, 8, 3, 6, 2),
    b5 = c(2, 12, 1, 7, 8, 5, 5, 6, NA),
    b6 = c(9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 9),
    b7 = c(1, 3, 7, 7, 4, 2, 2, 9, 5),
    b8 = c(NA, 8, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 6),
    b9 = c(4, 5, 7, 9, 5, 1, 1, 2, NA),
    b10 = c(14, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5))
```

I want to create a new column (NEW) which says BLUE or RED based on columns b2 and b3. so, if column b2 is Greater than or equal to 100 0R b3 is Greater than or equal to 75, then input BLUE otherwise input RED.

So that I will have something like this:

```
my_df <- data.frame(
        b1 = c(2, 6, 3, 6, 4, 2, 1, 9, NA), 
        b2 = c(100, 4, 106, 102, 6, 6, 1, 1, 7), 
        b3 = c(75, 79, 8, 0, 2, 3, 9, 5, 80), 
        b4 = c(NA, 6, NA, 10, 12, 8, 3, 6, 2),
        b5 = c(2, 12, 1, 7, 8, 5, 5, 6, NA),
        b6 = c(9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 9),
        b7 = c(1, 3, 7, 7, 4, 2, 2, 9, 5),
        b8 = c(NA, 8, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 6),
        b9 = c(4, 5, 7, 9, 5, 1, 1, 2, NA),
        b10 = c(14, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5),
        NEW = c("BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED", "BLUE"))
```

I have been able to work this out using this:

```
library (tidyverse)
greater_threshold <- 99.9
greater_threshold1 <- 74.9

my_df1 <- my_df %>%
mutate(NEW = case_when(b2 > greater_threshold ~ "BLUE",
b3  > greater_threshold1 ~ "BLUE",
+ T~"RED"))
```

At the moment, you can see that I am setting my 'greater threshold' to be slightly less than the required value. Although it works well. My question is this. Is there a way I set set my 'greater threshold to be ≥ 100 for b2 and ≥ 75 for b3.

Comment: Your question is not clear.   Can't it be set of `greater_theshold <- 100; greater_threshold1 <- 75` and then use `>=` in place of `>` ?

Comment: Thanks. That it. Thats what I have been forgetting to input (the greater than or equal sign (>=) instead of >

Comment: `case_when(b2 >= 100 | b3 >= 75 ~ "BLUE", TRUE ~ "RED")` and `if_else(b2 >= 100 | b3 >= 75, "BLUE", "RED")` are both sufficient to do what you described.

Comment: ≥ in R --> `>=`

Answer (score 0):

For this example, I'd go whit `if_else` instead of `case_when`:

```r
library(dplyr)

greater_threshold <- 100
greater_threshold1 <- 75

my_df <- data.frame(
  b1 = c(2, 6, 3, 6, 4, 2, 1, 9, NA),
  b2 = c(100, 4, 106, 102, 6, 6, 1, 1, 7),
  b3 = c(75, 79, 8, 0, 2, 3, 9, 5, 80),
  b4 = c(NA, 6, NA, 10, 12, 8, 3, 6, 2),
  b5 = c(2, 12, 1, 7, 8, 5, 5, 6, NA),
  b6 = c(9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 9),
  b7 = c(1, 3, 7, 7, 4, 2, 2, 9, 5),
  b8 = c(NA, 8, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 6),
  b9 = c(4, 5, 7, 9, 5, 1, 1, 2, NA),
  b10 = c(14, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5)
) 

my_df1 <- my_df %>%
  mutate(
    NEW = if_else(
      b2 >= greater_threshold | b3 >= greater_threshold1,
      "BLUE",
      "RED"
    )
  )

my_df1
# b1  b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9 b10  NEW
# 1  2 100 75 NA  2  9  1 NA  4  14 BLUE
# 2  6   4 79  6 12  2  3  8  5   2 BLUE
# 3  3 106  8 NA  1  4  7  4  7   4 BLUE
# 4  6 102  0 10  7  6  7  5  9   2 BLUE
# 5  4   6  2 12  8  7  4  1  5   1  RED
# 6  2   6  3  8  5  6  2  4  1   1  RED
# 7  1   1  9  3  5  6  2  1  1   1  RED
# 8  9   1  5  6  6  7  9  3  2   1  RED
# 9 NA   7 80  2 NA  9  5  6 NA   5 BLUE
```